# glyphicon and text links on different lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm trying to design a dropdown menu with Glyphicons on Rails 4.0.0 using Bootstrap 3.0.2. However, the Glyphicons and the texts with links don't show up on the same line. Here is my code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <%= gravatar_for(current_user, size: 20) %> <span class="caret"></span></a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> 
            <%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
            <%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></a>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>

        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>
            <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now, if I replace the links with pure text, here is my code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <%= gravatar_for(current_user, size: 20) %> <span class="caret"></span></a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> 
            Profile</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
            Settings</a>
        </li>

        <li class="divider"></li>

        <li>
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>
            Sign Out</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now it works perfectly.

Could anyone please help and let me know what was done incorrectly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: How is `<%= link_to ... %>` being rendered? The only thing I can think of is that it is being rendered as a block element rather than an inline element or text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The display style of anchor in the dropdown is set to `block`. `display:block;` set the hover effect to 100% width of the menu.

`.dropdown-menu > li > a {display:inline;}` will put your link and glyphicon on one line, but break the hover effect.

Try to add the glyphicon inside your link:

```
   <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Action</a></li>
```

Comment: I did `.dropdown-menu > li > a, .dropdown-menu > li > a > .glyphicon { display: inline-block; }`, which worked in more cases.